# Recoding and Sending Audio file with Axios on Safari

Tags: ios, laravel, audio, axios, safari

I am trying to record and send an audio file to a Laravel backend. Everything **is working fine on Chrome and Firefox**, but **on Safari** after sending the form, the file is missing. Any ideas or solutions on how I can understand and solve this problem?

Recording the audio file

```
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
      const chunks = []

      recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
        chunks.push(event.data)
      })

      const audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/webm' })
      const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
      const filename = `audio_${timestamp}.wav`
      const audioFile = new File([audioBlob], filename, { type: 'audio/wav' })
```

Sending the form

```
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('audio', audioFile, filename)

      console.log('formData:', formData.getAll('audio'))
      File {name: "audio_1686845222667.wav", lastModified: 1686845222667, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1758, type: "audio/wav", …}

      const config = {
            headers: {
              //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
            },
          }

      const response = await axios.post('/recordaudio', formData, config)
```

Request on Safari

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAOTnIX35RdvABYSP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="audio_1686845222667.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundaryAOTnIX35RdvABYSP--
```

Example from Firefox (is working)

```
-----------------------------285208455512739247982911496103
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="audio_1686846593105.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav

OggS���������wb����mSsOpusHead8»�����OggS����������wb���ü*c9OpusTags���libopus unknown������ENCODER=Mozilla110.0.1OggS��@8������wb���!áµÿÿÿ3ÿ2ÿ1ÿ0ÿ4ÿ2ÿ3ÿ4ÿ4ÿ3ÿ5ÿ3øÿþøÿþøpêÀp¯qXºàm
æÐ9
pDëÀQ¨>øåYÜÙîó¥³¤Âo70³AqlÂÕþIëRÎ¥SÊTo_ÉVºa·þ}v2Iò5åíPDð&^Øu¼ë)âEÝ æÂ¡)R `ìÆ<×ºr×æ®%ìát/¼xÓ§uîh£¼nÅÕÕNÄD0QD4ò$sEVæûÖâIyU7(
»~x3ôöo)'3æi);r&    6û?á_ÏâË aÕÇ9è2 7â���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������"T   õ3¿úRõ?Á!ýÏÐ{üQçüQ8µÙ%!§¼¸K�L±Y¢¿Ül¨#S°úSN§6®Þ,à\*&ñ´&
ÅØ/Öè:uñRÇB;J³  
...
-----------------------------285208455512739247982911496103--
```

I tried using different filetypes and also using different content=types

'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',

Comment: No helpful logs on backend?